# How to get the data between two Dates and times in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the data between two datetime (e.g. between 9 and 10). How can this be done in Laravel:

```php
$sel_ans1 = Answer::where('user_id','!=', $u_id)
  ->whereBetween('created_at', '2019-09-04 09:00:00', '2019-09-04 10:00:00')
                    ->first();
```

Comment: Are you missing a close quote after `'2019-09-04 09:00:00`?

Comment: Still not working. Is this a correct syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->whereBetween('created_at', '2019-09-04 09:00:00', '2019-09-04 10:00:00')`

should be

`->whereBetween('created_at', ['2019-09-04 09:00:00', '2019-09-04 10:00:00'])`

Answer (score 3):

whereBetween from and to should be in array like following

```
  ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2019-09-04 09:00:00', '2019-09-04 10:00:00'])
```